# How to customize csv format data on Apex chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, apexcharts, datejs

When we use x-axis type as category but it emits same x-axis data on csv format.

```
      xaxis: {
        type: 'category',
      }
```

One way to customize csv format date and time is using x-axis type as datetime this one works but in my case i have to show only 28 days in a month so it is not working in my case.

```
      xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
      }
```

Any suggestion are appreciate.

Comment: You could either pre-process in javascript the data from the json source to transform the x values to the format you want, or, more likely, use `datetime` with the numerous apex options to customize it . I would advise adding more code, to the level where it can be run by responders, so we can give more specific solutions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have found solution